# Xcode Simulator targets show "(Rosetta)"

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, rosetta

In an old project I noticed that all Simulator targets had a **"(Rosetta)"** indication whereas the project only contains Apple silicon compatible code and libraries.

I would like to build and run on native Simulators, but cannot seem to do that.

Web searches only reveal information on how to set Rosetta checkmarks on the Xcode.app and the Simulator.app, however these checkmarks don't exist anymore (Xcode 14).

How can the Simulator be returned to non-Rosetta?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The solution was to open the project in Xcode, then go to:

Product > Destination > Destination Architectures > Show Apple Silicon Destinations

Comment: I wasted my 1 hr to get this, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 15.3 the menu name has changed slightly.
The solution for this version is to open the project in Xcode and then go to and select:

Product > Destination > Show All Run Destinations